# Distiungish between Composite fraction and Subtraction symbol in machine learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am working in a project name "Handwritten Math Evaluation"
SO what basically happen in this is that there are 11 classes of (0 - 9) and (+,-) each containing 50 clean handwritten digits in them. Then I trained a CNN model for it with 80 % of data used in training and 20 % using in testing of model which lead in a accuracy of 98.83 %. Here is the code for the architecture of CNN model :-

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import pickle 
np.random.seed(1212) 
import keras 
from keras.models import Model 
from keras.layers import *
from keras import optimizers 
from keras.layers import Input, Dense 
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense 
from keras.layers import Dropout 
from keras.layers import Flatten 
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D 
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D 
from keras.utils import np_utils 
from keras import backend as K  
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical 
from keras.models import model_from_json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Conv2D(30, (5, 5), input_shape =(28,28,1), activation ='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2))) 
model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3), activation ='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) 
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(128, activation ='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(50, activation ='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(12, activation ='softmax')) 
# Compile model 
model.compile(loss ='categorical_crossentropy', 
            optimizer ='adam', metrics =['accuracy']) 
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000)
```

Now each image in dataset is preprocesed as follows:-

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread(path)
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
rects = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in ctrs]
rect = rects[0]
im_crop =im_th[rect[1]:rect[1]+rect[3],rect[0]:rect[0]+rect[2]]
im_resize = cv2.resize(im_crop,(28,28))
im_resize = np.array(im_resize)
im_resize=im_resize.reshape(28,28)
```

I have made an evaluation function which solves simple expression like 7+8 :-

```
def evaluate(im):
    s = ''
    data = []
    im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in ctrs]
    look_up = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','-'] 
    i=0
    for c in ctrs:
        rect = boundingBoxes[i]
        im_crop = im_th[rect[1]:rect[1]+rect[3], rect[0]:rect[0]+rect[2]]
        im_resize = cv2.resize(im_crop,(28,28))
        im_resize = np.array(im_resize)
        im_resize = im_resize.reshape(28,28,1)
        data.append(im_resize)
        i+=1
    data = np.array(data)
    predictions = model.predict(data)
    i=0
    while i<len(boundingBoxes):
        rect = boundingBoxes[i]
        print(rect[2],rect[3])
        print(predictions[i])
        s += look_up[predictions[i].argmax()]
        i+=1
    return s
```

I need help extending this thought for Compund fractions but the problem is that they are identical to subtraction sign when resized to (28 , 28) so I need help in distuingish between them.

This is my first Question so please tell if any detail is left.

Comment: perhaps attach a couple of images demonstrating the issue.

Comment: If information is lost due to resizing then obviously you need to do something before resizing, in the preprocessing step, to help preserve the feature. The neural net does not play any role in this. Or have I misunderstood ?

Comment: No actually one way was to measure aspect ration of contour and set a inequality condition but it is not very much accurate